# As part of Default Outcome, go to next element of the loop

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

[image: Broad Flow]

Want to the default outcome of the decision to iterate to the next item of the Loop Variable but it moves to the end of loop.

[image: Decision Element]

Kindly correct me on what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You need the flow to come back to your loop component.  This should do it:
(Red line is your default.)

[image]